# Is Walter Greiner's Nuclear Models a good and still relevant book?

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations

The title encapsulates the essence. Is [Walter Greiner's Nuclear Models](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-60970-1) a good book for (advanced) nuclear physics? Is it still relevant today, almost 30 years after its publication, or are there topics which aren't up to date? Would you recommend this to an advanced undergraduate or a graduate student? If not, what are some other books with similar content that you would recommend? Answers to any of these questions are welcome!